# como añadir el resultado de una consulta a un Listview Android studio

Tags: android

vereis tengo dos consultas asociadas a dos botones el resultado de esa consulta debe mostrarse en un Listview como podria hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: aver la consulta la tengo dntro de una tarea asincrona dicha tarea se ejecuta al pulsar un boton quiero que el resultado se muestre en un list view crre el adaptador y cuando pongo cursor= a toda la select me da error

Answer (score 1):

Imposible darte una mejor respuesta a esto, pues no has puesto nada de tu adaptador etc....

```
Adaptador tuAdaptador;  
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor c= ....(tu consulta);
                    tuAdaptador=new Adaptador(tusParametros, c1);
                    tuAdaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView.setAdapter(tuAdaptador);
                }
            });
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor c= ....(tu consulta);
                    tuAdaptador=new Adaptador(tusParametros, c1);
                    tuAdaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView.setAdapter(tuAdaptador);
                }
            });
```

Comment: probare muchas gracias c:

Comment: aver las consultas las tengo dentro de una tarea asincrona son de msqlserver como hago para que me lo reconozca y me lo muestre en el listview por cierto los ... en cursor porque?

Comment: Si no pones nada de código no se te puede ayudar más, no podemos imaginarnos tu código como comprenderás. Un saludo.